# extract($_GET) PHP ends up with undefined variable

Tags: php, variables, undefined, versions

I am having trouble with:

> Notice: Undefined variable: detail in
>   /var/www/html/premysl/php/web_f7mysql.php on line 43

The mentioned line contains some condition with `$detail == NULL`, which (variable $detail) should be extracted via `extract($_GET)` written in different file.

Here's the thing - whole project is hosted in root of server with PHP 5.4.13 and works perfectly. Anyway, it doesn't run on a different server with PHP 5.3.3 (cli).

Unfortunately it is necessary to make it work on the second one. I guess there's some "compatibility" issue, maybe different settings.

Do you have any sugestions what to focus on?

Comment: You don't want to extract `$_GET`

Comment: ^ Seconded. This is why `register_globals` is a thing best left `Off` in the darkest corner of your configuration.

Comment: `"...a different server with PHP 5.3.3 (cli)"` you dont have access to $_GET from the command line, surely

Comment: `$detail == NULL` can be replaced with `empty($detail)` to "avoid" the undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line that reads like this:

```
$detail == NULL
```

Should be changed to combine `isset` and `!empty` like this:

```
isset($detail) && !empty($detail)
```

Also using `extract($_GET)` is a bit ridiculous. Instead just do this:

```
$detail = (isset($_GET['detail']) && !empty($_GET['detail'])) ? $_GET['detail'] : null;
```

Also as far as the actual error goes:

> Notice: Undefined variable: detail in /var/www/html/premysl/php/web_f7mysql.php on line 43

Then just stick this line within whatever function is causing this issue in `web_f7mysql.php`:

```
global $detail;
```